# beamer with equation or align : replace part of equation and keep alignment

Tags: beamer, equations, align

I'm creating a presentation with the `beamer` class. Assume I want to write this :

```
\begin{equation}
    f(x) 
    \only<1>{= \cos(x)}
    \only<2>{= 2\cos(x)}
\end{equation}
```

I have a problem because on the slide 2, the equation is longer and therefore
the equation is moving. If I replace `only` by `uncover`, there is a white
space on the slide 2.

I have the same problem for the `align` environment

```
\begin{align}
    f(x) &= \exp(x)\\
    \only<2>{&= \cos(x)}
    \only<3>{&= 2\cos(x)}
\end{align}
```

How can I replace part of an equation by something else without changing the placement of the other part of the equation ?

## Edit

I will be more precise. I would like to find an efficient way to replace the
right hand side of an equality (for `equation` or `align`) without adding
extra white space and such that it keeps the equal sign at the same place.

For example :

```
\begin{equation}
    \cos(x) = 
    \somecommand<1>{\dfrac{\exp{ix}+\exp{-ix}}{2}}
    \somecommand<2>{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{2n+1}x^{2n+1}}
    ...
    \somecommand<n>{some other equality with a given lenght}
\end{equation}
```

- If `\somecommand` is `\only` then the whole equality will move from slide 1 to 2.
- If `\somecommand` is `\uncover` then there will be a whitespace between the equal sign and the Taylor expansion on slide 2.
- Using `\hphantom` with `\alt` or `\temporal` might be a solution but it seems very complicated to use it for more then two slides

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problem using this solution (I know that it's not in
agreement with my question because I wanted to use `equation` or `align`)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\renewcommand*{\a}[1]{\hat a_{#1}^{\vphantom{\dagger}}}
\newcommand*{\ad}[1]{\hat a_{#1}^{\dagger}}
\renewcommand*{\c}[1]{\hat{c}_{#1}^{\vphantom{\dagger}}}
\newcommand*{\cd}[1]{\hat{c}_{#1}^{\dagger}}
\renewcommand*{\H}{\hat{H}}
\newcommand*{\T}{\hat{T}}
\newcommand*{\dsum}[1]{\displaystyle\sum_{#1}}
\newcommand*{\dsumd}[3]{\displaystyle\sum_{#1=#2}^{#3}}
\newcommand*{\dprod}[1]{\displaystyle\prod_{#1}}
\newcommand*{\dprodd}[3]{\displaystyle\prod_{#1=#2}^{#3}}
\newcommand*{\dbigotimesd}[3]{\displaystyle\bigotimes_{#1=#2}^{#3}}
\newcommand*{\dbigoplusd}[3]{\displaystyle\bigoplus_{#1=#2}^{#3}}
\newcommand*{\ket}[1]{\left|#1\right>}
\newcommand*{\ep}[1]{\left(#1\right)}
\renewcommand*{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\det}[1]{\mathrm{det}\ep{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{minipage}[h]{0.4\linewidth}
    $
    \T
    \only<1>{= \dbigoplusd{\alpha}{1}{N}\hat{T}_{\alpha}}
    \only<2-3>{= \dbigoplusd{\alpha}{1}{N}\hat{\vec{a}}^{\dagger}_{\alpha}T\hat{\vec{a}}^{\vphantom{\dagger}}_{\alpha}}
    \only<4->{= \dbigoplusd{\alpha}{1}{N}\dsumd{i}{1}{n}\omega_{i\alpha}\cd{i\alpha}\c{i\alpha}}
    $
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[h]{0.5\linewidth}
        \uncover<3->{
        \begin{align*}
            \cd{i\alpha} &= \dsumd{j}{1}{n}U_{ji}^{\alpha}\ad{j\alpha} &
            \omega_{i\alpha} &< \omega_{i+1\alpha}
        \end{align*}
        }
    \end{minipage}
    \uncover<5->{
    $
    \uncover<6->{\ket{\Psi_{G}}= }
    \only<5->{\uncover<6->{\hat{P}_{G}^{m}}\ket{\Psi}}
    \uncover<5->{=\uncover<6->{\hat{P}_{G}^{m}}\dbigotimesd{\alpha}{1}{N}\dprodd{i}{1}{mn/N}\alt<5-6>{\c{i\alpha}}{\dsumd{j}{1}{n}U_{ji}^{\alpha}\ad{j\alpha}}\ket{0}}
    \only<10->{\equiv \dsum{\mathcal{C}}\det{U_{\mathcal{C}}}\ket{\mathcal{C}}}
    $
    }
    \begin{center}
    \uncover<8->{
    $
    \ket{\mathcal{C}} \equiv \dbigotimesd{\alpha}{1}{N}\dprodd{i}{1}{mn/N}\ad{i_{\alpha}\alpha}\ket{0}
    $
    }
    \uncover<9->{
    $
    \dsumd{\alpha}{1}{N}\ad{i\alpha}\a{i\alpha}\ket{\mathcal{C}} = m 
    \qquad
    \dsumd{i}{1}{n}\ad{i\alpha}\a{i\alpha}\ket{\mathcal{C}} = \dsumd{i}{1}{n}\ad{i\beta}\a{i\beta}\ket{\mathcal{C}} 
    $
    }
    \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I hope this can help someone else...

Answer (score 8):

There are a number of ways of doing this. Here's one, using `\phantom{<stuff>}` to pad the missing `<stuff>` in the shorter equation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{A frame}

  \begin{equation}
    f(x) =
      \only<1>{\cos(x)\phantom{2}}
      \only<2>{2\cos(x)}
  \end{equation}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Placement of the `\phantom{<stuff>}` depends on how you want to examine the contents. For example, you could also try

```
f(x) = \alt<2>{2}{\phantom{2}}\cos(x)
```

[image]

Also see `\temporal` in the [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf).

---

For larger constructions, the best offer I can make is to identify the biggest (horizontally and vertically) element in the set of equations and store these in a macro and use another macro as a space-adjustment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\inserteqstrut}[1]{%
  \rlap{$\displaystyle#1$}%
  \phantom{\biggesteq}}
\begin{document}

% Store biggest equation in set
\newcommand{\biggesteq}{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{2n+1}x^{2n+1}}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{A frame}

  \begin{equation}
    \cos(x) = 
    \only<1>{\inserteqstrut{\dfrac{\exp{ix}+\exp{-ix}}{2}}}
    \only<2>{\inserteqstrut{\biggesteq}}
    \only<3>{\inserteqstrut{\text{some equality}}}
  \end{equation}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If you have two separate equations that make up the "biggest", use a combination of `\vphantom` (for the tallest/deepest) and `\hphantom` (for the widest/longest). Here's such an example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\inserteqstrut}[1]{%
  \rlap{$\displaystyle#1$}%
  \phantom{\biggesteq}}
\begin{document}

% Store biggest equation in set
\newcommand{\biggesteq}{%
  \vphantom{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n}% tallest/deepest
  \hphantom{\text{some other equality}}}% longest/widest

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{A frame}

  \begin{equation}
    \cos(x) = 
    \only<1>{\inserteqstrut{\tfrac{\exp{ix}+\exp{-ix}}{2}}}
    \only<2>{\inserteqstrut{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n}}
    \only<3>{\inserteqstrut{\text{some other equality}}}
  \end{equation}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thx, I was almost going to use this solution but as my equations are quite long, I was not willing to write them twice. and this will only work if I add stuff to the previous equation. for instance, if I replace `\cos(x)` by let's say `\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1}`

Comment: @PinkFloyd: My latter suggestion is to keep the structure the same, but use `\alt` or `\temporal` to change the specific components. Not sure whether that's a feasible alternative or not.

Comment: well `\alt` or `\temporal` are better because I wouldn't have to rewrite the equation but it doesn't keep the correct alignment when I replace some part on an equation by something that is completely different

Comment: @PinkFloyd: Well then, please provide something more substantive in terms of what you mean. It is not always possible to have your cake and eat it, but we can try...

Comment: sorry, i will edit my question

Comment: @PinkFloyd: I've added some more cake...

Answer (score 0):

Although Werner's solution is clearly cleaner, I find that sometimes a quick and dirty solution is to simply insert some extra spacing in one of the alternative overlays. For example I used this code:

```
\frame{
  \frametitle{What: the Perron method}

  We split coordinates $x = (x_+, x_-)$%
\uncover<2->{, change the initial time $t_0$ in the unstable part}
\uncover<3->{and let $t_0 \to \infty$}
  \begin{alignat*}{2}
    x_+(t) &\mapsto
              \only<1  |handout:0>{e^{t\,A_+} \cdot x_+(0)\hspace{0.86cm}}
              \only<2-3|handout:0>{e^{(t-\alert{t_0})\,A_+} \cdot x_+(\alert{t_0})}
              \only<4-           >{\qquad\alert{\ldots}\hspace{1.59cm}}
           && \only< -3|handout:0>{+}
              \only<4-           >{-\,}
              \int_{\only<1  |handout:0>{0}
                    \only<2-3|handout:0>{\alert{\smash{t_0}}\!\!}
                    \only<4-           >{t}}
                  ^{\only<1-3|handout:0>{\smash{t}}
                    \only<4-           >{\alert{\smash{\infty}}}\!\!\!\!}
                  e^{(t-\tau)\,A_+} \cdot r_+((x_+,x_-)(\tau)) \d\tau,\\
    x_-(t) &\mapsto
              e^{t\,A_-} \cdot x_-(0)
           &&+\int_{0\,}^t e^{(t-\tau)\,A_-} \cdot r_-((x_+,x_-)(\tau)) \d\tau.
  \end{alignat*}
  \uncover<3->{%
    We consider this rewritten map $T$ for bounded curves
    $x \in B(\R;\R^n)$ only.
  }

}
```

to create slide 7 of [this beamer presentation](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~jelderin/includes/get.php?file=talk-VU-perron-method.pdf).

Comment: you have to set the horizontal spacing by hand... not really efficient...

Comment: @PinkFloyd: True, but it saves me from inserting more complicated `\smash` and `\hphantom` commands, and presentations anyways often need a bit of this kind of manual tweaking.