# Long equation together with an image in one slide

Tags: beamer, columns, overlays, wrapfigure

The figure that I want to put it (left or right side) in the slide has to be of half of the `textwidth` (or at least `0.45\textwidth}`). How can I have these long equation and that figure in one slide without any resize trick?

<del>My solution is to use the Beamer overlay feature so that in slides 1 and 2 we have the figure (in the right side) with the first line of the equation and in the rest of the slide we only show the equations. How can do this?</del>

Your solutions will certainly be interesting.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\[
\begin{aligned}
S & =\int_{a}^{b}   f(x)g(x) \mathrm{~d} x\\
&=\int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2b^{2}-x^{2}}}\right)^{2}} \sqrt{1-\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2b^{2}-x^{2}}}\right)^{2}} \mathrm{~d} x\\
&=\int_{a}^{b}  \dots\\
&=   \dots
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Usually you should ask only one question per question. In this question there are two: 1. How to show image and long equations side by side. 2. How to shod the equation step by step.

Comment: No, my question is just the first one. I am not an amateur user.

Comment: So why do you ask: "How can do this?" at the end of the second paragraph? Please do ask only what you want to know, but not what you already know.

Comment: This is just my attempt which also answers the original question if anyone can do it.

Comment: Sorry, but currently there are two different questions. So IMHO it is not focused.

Comment: @C.F.G Maybe you can edit your question to explain why placing image and equation side-by-side and uncovering the equation stepwise are so interconnected that they can't be separated into individual questions? Two questions would certainly make it much easier to find appropriate duplicates.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz: it is just my try, you can ignore that.

Comment: @cabohah: your answer is same as Zarko one. (I am emphasizing that I am aware of `\pause`  `\only` `\onslide` ...

Comment: @C.F.G Similar but not the same. Zarko's answer produces one slide no overlays and it uses different math code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- make left column narrower and right wider
- break long rquation into two line

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.55\textwidth}
\[
\begin{aligned}
S   & = \int_{a}^{b}   f(x)g(x) \mathrm{~d} x\\
    & = \begin{multlined}[t]
            \int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2b^{2}-x^{2}}}\right)^{2}}\cdot    \\
                         \sqrt{1-\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2b^{2}-x^{2}}}\right)^{2}} \mathrm{~d} x
        \end{multlined}     \\
    & = \int_{a}^{b}  \dots\\
    & = \dots
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
in original answer I overlooked that you also like uncover equations on the right side of frame. This can be dun on different ways, for example by use of the macro `uncover`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{column}%
\begin{column}{0.55\textwidth}
\[ 
\begin{aligned}
S   & = \int_{a}^{b}   f(x)g(x) \mathrm{~d} x\\
\uncover<2-> {    & = \begin{multlined}[t]
            \int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2b^{2}-x^{2}}}\right)^{2}}\cdot    \\
                         \sqrt{1-\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2b^{2}-x^{2}}}\right)^{2}} \mathrm{~d} x
        \end{multlined}}     \\
\uncover<3-> {    & = \int_{a}^{b}  \dots}\\
\uncover<4-> {    & = \dots}
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Showed are only first three slides:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Instead of breaking the equation, you could implement what you described in your question as it follows. I also proposed here a slightly different approach placing the image in the slide independently of the slide content taking advantage of TikZ `[overlay, remember picture]` common pattern.

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage{lmodern,tikz,amsmath}
    
    % Taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/203952/128737
    % Requires amsmath
    \newcommand{\inserteqstrut}[1]{%
        \rlap{$\displaystyle#1$}%
        \phantom{\biggesteq}}
        
    % Store biggest equation in set
    \newcommand{\biggesteq}{
        \int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2b^{2}-x^{2}}}\right)^{2}}
        \sqrt{1-\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2b^{2}-x^{2}}}\right)^{2}} \mathrm{~d} x
    }    
    
    \begin{document}
        \begin{frame}{As you envisioned}
            \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{0.7\textheight}
                \[
                \begin{aligned}
                    S & = \inserteqstrut{\int_{a}^{b}   f(x)g(x) \mathrm{~d} x}\\
                    \only<2>{
                      & = \inserteqstrut{\biggesteq} \\
                      & = \inserteqstrut{\int_{a}^{b}  \dots} \\
                      & = \inserteqstrut{\dots}
                    }
                \end{aligned}
                \]
                \begin{onlyenv}<1>
                    \hfill\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image}
                \end{onlyenv}
            \end{overlayarea}
        \end{frame}
    
        \begin{frame}[t]{Placing image with TikZ}
            \[
            \begin{aligned}
                S & =\int_{a}^{b}   f(x)g(x) \mathrm{~d} x\\
                  &=\biggesteq\\
                  &=\int_{a}^{b}  \dots\\
                  &=   \dots
            \end{aligned}
            \]
            \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
                \node[anchor=north west] at (current page.center)
                    {\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image}};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

[image: outcome]

Few comments:

- If you do not use some technique to work against it, beamer will shift content horizontally and potentially also vertically in your equation. I used [this nice technique](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/203952/128737) and in that answer you can also see what to do if you want to avoid vertical shifts within the formula.
- In general, the `overlayarea` environment helps in fixing content vertically consistently among overlays.
- You might want to read on [beamer manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) the difference between `\only` and `\uncover` (and friends). They work differently w.r.t. reserving space when building the slide.

Comment: it has a little jump that make it like two different slide!

Comment: @Axel You can avoid the jumping if you make all frames top aligned. I like the layout, looks imho better than columns.

Comment: Just to clarify, the last frame was just kind of technically off-topic here and proposed as different alternative (it uses TikZ machinery on top). Yes, there is a jump between the two frames due to the `[t]` frame alignment in the last `frame` environment (as samcarter noticed). Just go the way you prefer. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use,e.g., `\visible` to show the equation step by step. If you split one line into two, just activate them in one step:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{align*}
\visible<2->{S & =\int_{a}^{b}   f(x)g(x) \mathrm{~d} x}\\
\visible<3->{ &=\int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2b^{2}-x^{2}}}\right)^{2}}} \\
\visible<3->{  &\quad\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2b^{2}-x^{2}}}\right)^{2}} \mathrm{~d} x\\}
\visible<4->{&=\int_{a}^{b}  \dots\\}
\visible<5->{&=   \dots}
\end{align*}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: all slides]

Answer (score 1):

**My solution but not the ideal one:**

I added an `\only<2>{\phantom{t}}%` in same column of the figure one. (IMAO The codes I have written below **are not standard nor optimized!**)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.49\textwidth}
\only<1>{\[
\begin{aligned}
S & =\int_{a}^{b}   f(x)g(x) \mathrm{~d} x\\
&\phantom{=\int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2b^{2}-x^{2}}}\right)^{2}} \sqrt{1-\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2b^{2}-x^{2}}}\right)^{2}} \mathrm{~d} x}\\
&\phantom{=\int_{a}^{b}  \dots}\\
&\phantom{=   \dots}
\end{aligned}
\]}
\only<2>{\[
\begin{aligned}
S & =\int_{a}^{b}   f(x)g(x) \mathrm{~d} x\\
&=\int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2b^{2}-x^{2}}}\right)^{2}} \sqrt{1-\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2b^{2}-x^{2}}}\right)^{2}} \mathrm{~d} x\\
&=\int_{a}^{b}  \dots\\
&=   \dots
\end{aligned}
\]}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.49\textwidth}
\includegraphics<1>[width=\textwidth]{example-image}%
\only<2>{\phantom{t}}%
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{document}
```

[image]